# Datatable - Translate elements of response

Tags: angular, datatable

I created a datatable with [Angular Datatable](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome) and the *clasic ajax* way. I need to translate some elements of response to text using [NGX Translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core). I catch response and try to use this.translate like this

```
 url: Service.API_ENDPOINT, dataSrc: function (json) {
      for(var i=0;i< json['body'].length; i++){
           json['body'][i].profile = this.translate.instant('profiles' + json['body'][i].profile);
      }
      return json['body']
  },
```

But returns

> Cannot read property 'translate' of undefined

How can take *this.translate* method and use it inside url method of datatable?

Comment: translate is undefined because context is changed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the context as below.

```
  var self = this;
url: Service.API_ENDPOINT, dataSrc: function (json) {
      for(var i=0;i< json['body'].length; i++){
           json['body'][i].profile = self.translate.instant('profiles' + json['body'][i].profile);
      }
      return json['body']
  },
```

Comment: If my answer works for you, please upvote the answer.